# passing parameter with js/ajax to a php document

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(":input").focusout(function () {

    var a= $(this).closest("tr").attr('id');
    var b= $(this).closest("td").attr('id');
    var data = $(this).attr("value");

   $.post("database.php",
   {trAdress: a, tdAdress: b }, function(data){ alert("Data Loaded: " + data); }); });});
```

I want to pass trAdress and tdAdress also data parameters to a php document... Can anyone help me how can I get these parameters in a php document_?

Comment: Through `$_POST`, perhaps? How much of PHP do you know? What's your PHP file looking like currently?

Comment: I only want to get these values and use them as database input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you sent them using POST, you can access the values sent in the form using `$_POST` superglobal variable:

```
<?php
$trAddress = $_POST['trAddress'];
$tdAddress = $_POST['tdAddress'];

// your code here
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Answer (score 1):

They will be set in the `$_POST` array as `$_POST['trAdress']` and `$_POST['tdAdress']`.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST["trAdress"]` and `$_POST["tdAdress"]` will get you the values